# Feel confuse git commit problem about the order

Tags: git

There is a weird problem when we use git.

[image: t]

This node `7258863646` is the earlier commit;

[image: t]

And the files changed at this node `7258863646` is like this. It was changed at 16 hours age.

[image: t]

At the latest node `329c6a7df6` , the changed files was changed long time ago.

The node `7258863646` seem not working. I dont know why.

Nodes after `7258863646`, No one changed those files.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: On the second picture you are pointing to a wrong commit. It is not `329c6a7df6` but `b64d0...` made 7 hours ago.

Comment: Did you mean third picture?
`329c6a7df` is current commit node.

Comment: The `b64d0..` is latest commit about this directory previous `329c6a7d`.
But `b64d0..` is nothing to do with those files which changed by `7258863646` commit.

sorry for my bad english again. ><

Comment: Look at the first picture.
the files ABCD changed and commit at `7258863646` in the red frame.
and after `7258863646` commit, the files ABCD were not changed at those commits in the yellow frame. so I feel so confused.`7258863646` seems to be not working at this develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

You mean those commits after `7258863646` never been changed by you and `7258863646` was the last commit to this branch? 
But if you click on those commits, what do you see? Are these were you changes? 
I think `7258863646` commit was made when head of your branch (you mentioned develop) was pointing the wrong place not the tip of the branch

Comment: Those commits after `7258863646`, The edited time of `A B C D files` are earlier then edited time of `A B C D files` at `7258863646`. `A B C D files` are latest at `7258863646` but those commits after `7258863646`.
The content of those commits was nothing to do with `A B C D files`.
I just entered those commits to see the state of files. and found `A B C D files` were earlier. 
So i felt confused.
Thank for replying.